# Should the entire element on my burner on top of electric stove turn red when turned on?

Tags: kitchens

I just bought a new Frigidaire electric range. On top of stove burner the element does not turn completely red. Should the entire element turn red? Not just partially.

Comment: There's some variation in how hot the elements get, particularly at the ends of the element and near physical support points: https://www.google.com/search?q=electric+stove+element&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=rki8VP-ALIW7yQTy9oGgCg&ved=0CAkQ_AUoAg&biw=1007&bih=537

Answer (score 1):

It might or might not be an issue, depending on what is actually happening and element type.

For "normal" coil elements, if one spot on the element gets red significantly earlier than the rest of the element, [it's time to replace the element before it burns out and starts arcing.](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/20894/why-is-my-fuse-board-buzzing-when-im-using-the-shower/21707#21707)

A slightly uneven redness is not a problem. As such, pictures would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I  have to assume this is a glass top type. If so, it might be defective OR it might be a design feature. You'd have to check the specific model number to find out.

If this is an open element type, it would not work this way, as the entire burner is conducting current. I highly doubt this is the case, however.

Answer (score 0):

Some elements have size settings. Your dial may turn one direction for small pots and the other direction for large. It may also have a pot size sensor.

Please post your model number.

Answer (score 0):

This is not necessarily an issue. See the related question about oven heating element [HERE](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/52953/is-it-a-problem-that-the-entire-element-in-my-electric-oven-is-not-red)